# Oracle lock issue - ORA-00054: resource busy - while creating a foreign key

Tags: oracle, locking

Initial situation:

- A table PARENT_TABLE with a primary key on its column PK_COL.
- A table CHILD_TABLE1 with a foreign key on PARENT_TABLE(PK_COL).

I insert a line into CHILD_TABLE1 in a transaction and do not commit.

Then I try to create a table CHILD_TABLE2 symmetrical to CHILD_TABLE1 in another session.
But an `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired` is raised when I create the foreign key, because of the ongoing insertion in CHILD_TABLE1.

I don't understand why Oracle is preventing the foreign key creation: there is no modification performed on PARENT_TABLE.

Please help.

To reproduce under sqlplus:

```
set autocommit off

create table PARENT_TABLE(PK_COL varchar(10));
alter table PARENT_TABLE add constraint PK_CONSTRAINT primary key (PK_COL);
insert into PARENT_TABLE values ('foo');
commit;

create table CHILD_TABLE1(CHILD_PK_COL varchar(10), FK_COL varchar(10));
alter table CHILD_TABLE1 add constraint CHILD_TABLE1_CONSTRAINT foreign key (FK_COL) references PARENT_TABLE(PK_COL);
create index CHILD_TABLE1_INDEX on CHILD_TABLE1(FK_COL);
insert into CHILD_TABLE1 values ('bar', 'foo');
```

In another console:

```
alter session set ddl_lock_timeout=10;
create table CHILD_TABLE2(CHILD_PK_COL varchar(10), FK_COL varchar(10));
alter table CHILD_TABLE2 add constraint CHILD_TABLE2_CONSTRAINT foreign key (FK_COL) references PARENT_TABLE(PK_COL);
```

Funny: with NOVALIDATE in CHILD_TABLE2_CONSTRAINT creation, the execution is hanging...

Comment: Here is a helpful resource: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm#BABDDFHB

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link. Unfortunately, the main sample is the other way around: lock (Or not) on child table when a row of the parent table is modified. In my case I only modify a child table content. There is even a note: **DML on a child table does not acquire a table lock on the parent table.** which would say that I should not have a lock in my case!

Comment: Are you on v11.1? If not, verify the docs for your exact version.

Comment: Both doc and my database are 11.2.

Answer (score 2):

> You are not modifying something in the parent table. But you're
>   actually, trying to refer its primary key in your child table. Before
>   establishing a relationship or any `DDL` with table, it has to be free
>   of locks.

So, before creating this constraint, Oracle do check for existing locks over the referred table(`PARENT_TABLE`). A lock over a table(Table Level Lock,in this context) is actually for a reason to adhere to the `ACID` properties.

One best example to understand its importance is `ON DELETE CASCADE` which means if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted.

So, when there's a uncommitted insert/update/delete over the child table referring a parent table. No other referential constraint can be created to the parent. Just to avoid a deadlock or chaos.

> To be more crisp, when you have an uncommitted insert in your child table.
>   There's a lock over your parent table as well. So all other further DDLs referring it will be made wait.

You can use this query to check the same.

```
SELECT c.owner,
  c.object_name,
  c.object_type,
  b.sid,
  b.serial#,
  b.status,
  b.osuser,
  b.machine
FROM v$locked_object a ,
  v$session b,
  dba_objects c
WHERE b.sid     = a.session_id
AND a.object_id = c.object_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the LOCKED_MODE explanation in you query:

```
DECODE(a.LOCKED_MODE, 0,'NONE', 1,'NULL', 2,'ROW SHARE (RS/SS)', 3,'ROW EXCLUSIVE (RX/SX)', 4,'SHARE (S)', 5,'SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE (SRX/SSX)', 6,'EXCLUSIVE (X)', NULL) LOCK_MODE.
```

Here is the result:

```
OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         LOCK_MODE                         SID    SERIAL# STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------- ----------------------------- ---------- ---------- --------
PARENT_TABLE                   TABLE               ROW EXCLUSIVE (RX/SX)              71          8694 INACTIVE
CHILD_TABLE1                   TABLE               ROW EXCLUSIVE (RX/SX)              71          8694 INACTIVE
```

RX/SX is a table lock so it prevents any DDL operation (That seems to be said in the doc). This lock is used on both parent and child. I suppose that the lock is added on parent to at least prevent it from being deleted so we would lost the pending update on the child table.

That said, I still have no solution. Suppose that the parent table is a **manufacturer**. There is a child **car** table and we are inserting plenty of new cars in that table on the fly. There is a foreign key from **car** to **manufacturer**. Now there is a new product that we want to manage: "bicycles". So we want to create a **bicycle** table similar to **car**. But we cannot create the table as we are performing insertions in **car**. Seems a very simple use case... How to support it?

=====
Edit:
There might be no solution. [Here is a guy with the same issue](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:292016138754#7838048831876).

Comment: You consider the example I mentioned in my answer. `ON DELETE CASCADE` would delete all the child entries when a parent is deleted. Just Imagine, for this to happen. All the relationships should be in control. When you have a uncommited insert in your child. And the parent is deleted some where else.. What would happen now?? So, to be more abstract, Oracle locks the table for any DMLs, or any new relationships.